# How to remove transparency of a layer?

Tags: modeling, transparency

I'm new to Blender and I am making that famous doughnut. I seem to have accidentally made the icing layer transparent, meaning that it doesn't show up in Edit Mode and I cannot sculpt in Sculpt Mode. Instead, it ends up altering the doughnut underneath. How do I get my icing back?
[image: Sculpt Mode where you can see the transparency texture]

[image: Edit Mode where you can see the icing disappears]

Comment: it is very helpful, if you can show us your blend file...

Answer (score 1):

If it only disappears in *Edit Mode*, you might have accidentally hit <kbd>H</kbd> to hide the selection while the complete mesh was selected.

Go to *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It toggles annotations in the viewport and only shows models and not vertices in edit mode.